# Kodaira-Spencer theory of deformation done right

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, moduli-spaces, deformation-theory, complex-manifolds

I thought in asking this question on Math StackExchange, but by my experience I don' t think anyone will notice me. Recently, I started studying deformation of complex manifolds in the sense of Kodaira and Spencer, but some things relating infinitesimal approximations are not clear for me.

Let $\varpi: \mathscr{M} \twoheadrightarrow D$ be a analytic family of compact complex manifolds such that $D \in \mathbb{C}^m$ is disk centered at the origin, $M = M_0$ is covered by coordinate charts $\{ U_i \}$ and the radius of $D$ is small enough to $\{ U_i \times D  \}$ cover $\mathscr{M}$. Now, let $(\zeta_i^1 (z_i , t), …,\zeta_i^n(z_i^n, t), t^1, …,t^m)$ denote the coordinates of $U_i \times D$, then, in the literature, without any formal justificative, it's stated that $$\frac{\partial \zeta_i^j}{\overline{\partial z_i}^k} = \sum_{l} \varphi_{lk}^i (t) \frac{\partial \zeta_i^j}{\partial z_i^l}$$ 
holds. The informal justificative usually done is by saying that if $t$ is close enough to $0$, then $pr^{(0, 1)}|_{T_t^{(0, 1)}} : T_t^{(0, 1)} \rightarrow T^{(0, 1)} $ defines an isomorphism. So it is possible to construct a map $$\varphi(t) = pr^{(1, 0)}\circ (pr^{(0, 1)}|_{T_t^{(0, 1)}})^{-1}: T^{(0, 1)} \longrightarrow T^{(1, 0)} $$ and it satisfies $(1 + \varphi(t)) (v) \in T_t^{(0, 1)}$ for all $v \in T^{(0, 1)}$.

Clearly, $pr^{(0, 1)}|_{T_t^{(0, 1)}} : T_t^{(0, 1)} \rightarrow T^{(0, 1)} $ being an isomorphism is the same as the complex strutcture being the same for all $t$, **so how is possible to make this construction of $\varphi$ more formal? Why the equality above holds?**

Maybe the assumption "t close enough to 0" should be formalized in terms of nilpotent elements, something like a kind of prorepresentable functor, such that $pr^{(0, 1)}|_{T_t^{(0, 1)}} : T_t^{(0, 1)} \rightarrow T^{(0, 1)} $ being an isomorphism makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** As noted by Peter Dalakov, the assertion that the splitting of $T_{\mathbb{C}}$ does not change, is totally wrong. So the remaining question is: why $$\frac{\partial \zeta_i^j}{\overline{\partial z_i}^k} = \sum_{l} \varphi_{lk}^i (t) \frac{\partial \zeta_i^j}{\partial z_i^l}$$ holds?

Comment: I gave some links to the literature for a somewhat similar question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99912/almost-complex-structure-approach-to-deformation-of-compact-complex-manifolds?rq=1

Comment: @PeterDalakov Thanks, I have already seen this similar question and I have already studied the references. But they don't exactly solve my question. The condition for "t close enough to 0" stated as the isomorphism of the bundles still making no sense at all. As I said in my question , this is equivalent to the splitting of the complexified tangent bundle doesn't change.

Comment: I am having hard time understanding what the question is. The projection being an isomorphism doesn't mean that the complex structure is "the same". But you seem to be unhappy with the very fact that it is an isom, so I am confused. I would suggest to 1) think about the case of curves 2) Look at the way we introduce charts in grassmannians, e.g., Voisin, vol.1, 10.1.1           Or maybe the question is about the dependence of $\phi$ on $t$: why is it holomorphic, etc?

Comment: Notice $T^{1,0}$ is not the holomorphic tangent bundle of $M_0$, but rather the underlying smooth complex vector bundle. I.e., as sheaves of $C^\infty$-modules, $T_{M_0}\subset T^{1,0}\subset T_{\mathbb{C}}$ and $T^{1,0}=T\otimes_{\mathcal{O}}C^\infty$

Comment: @PeterDalakov Thanks, I'm trying to follow your advices. Maybe I'm missing something very trivial. But saying that $pr^{(0, 1)}|_{T_t^{(0, 1)}} : T_t^{(0, 1)} \rightarrow T^{(0, 1)} $ is an isomorphism, is exactly the same thing as saying that the splitting of $T_{\mathbb{C}}$ is the same for all $t$, so the almost complex structure does not change at all. So, I'm unhappy with the definition of $t$ close enough to $0$. Furthermore the above equality $\frac{\partial \zeta_i^j}{\overline{\partial z_i}^k} = \sum_{l} \varphi_{lk}^i (t) \frac{\partial \zeta_i^j}{\partial z_i^l}$ is not explained.

Comment: Maybe there is to one-to-one correspondence between splittings of the complexefied tangent bundle $T_{\mathbb{C}}$ and almost complex structures on $M$ as it's suggested in Huybrechts' book.

Comment: $T_{\mathbb{C}}= T^{1,0}\oplus T^{0,1}\simeq T^{1,0}_t\oplus T^{0,1}_t$ does not imply that the two summands are equal. The equation that you write gives the relation between the two decompositions.

Comment: @PeterDalakov Yes, but $pr^{(0, 1)}|_{T_t^{(0, 1)}} : T_t^{(0, 1)} \rightarrow T^{(0, 1)} $ being an isomorphism implies that the two summands are equal.

Comment: OK, I won't comment more on this. The summands are isomorphic, but are different as subbundles of $T_{\mathbb{C}}$. Think of "rotation of axes" in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @PeterDalakov Ops! You're right. I failed in a simple linear algebra problem! But I still cannot understand $$\frac{\partial \zeta_i^j}{\overline{\partial z_i}^k} = \sum_{l} \varphi_{lk}^i (t) \frac{\partial \zeta_i^j}{\partial z_i^l}$$ why the equality holds. In the literature it's just assumed that it holds, so...

Comment: Maybe you should look again at that linear algebra problem and write the rotated axis as the graph of a function. See also the other linked question, and maybe work it out in dimension one: the Cauchy-Riemann equation $\overline{\partial}\zeta=0$ is replaced by $(\overline{\partial}-\varphi \partial)\zeta=0$.

Comment: @PeterDalakov Thanks again for the hint. And yes, I can see for the dimension $1$ case, because it's just a Beltrami differential. However, for the general case it's not clear that it will not appear any anti-holomorphic vector field in the right side of my above equation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure which book you are using . But from Kodaira, Morrow's book $\it complex$ $\it manifolds$ page 149-151, the construction of vector-value $(0,1)-$form $\varphi$ will tell you why the equality holds, also you will see why $t$ is required to be close enough to 0.